# Get real ip address using CloudFlare

Tags: php, cloudflare

How can I get the real ip address from the user, when using CloudFlares service?

I need the real ip for the user connecting, and using this:

```
 $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] ? $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"] : $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Will only show **my** correct IP address, not the user connecting.